# For loop with multiple variables in LiveCycle

Tags: loops, livecycle

Essentially I have a calculated field that I want to end up with a rating %.

That rating % is going to be based on the values selected from a series of dropdowns in a subform. The drop downs have values from 0 to 5. Drop downs with a value of 0 are to be ignored and not included in the calculation.

For example, if there are 5 drop downs and 1 has a selcted value of 0, the rating percentage would be based on the values of 4 of the drop downs out of a maximum score of 20.

Here is what I have so far in the calculated field:

```
var Fields = xfa.resolveNodes("Page2.Comm_Sub.CommRtng[*]");
var Answered = 0;
var Values = 0;
var Rating = (Values / (Answered*5)) * 100

for (i=0; i<= Fields.length; i++){
     if (Fields.item(i).rawValue > 0) {
     Answered++;
     Values += Fields.item(i).rawValue;
     }
}
this.rawValue = Rating
```

As I said, it's a pretty basic loop (I think), but I cannot get it to output a value in Answered or Values or Rating or at least I don't think it is. For instance when I input xfa.host.messageBox(Value) in the code to see what's happening, I only ever get a blank messageBox, same when I use "Values". So I know the loop is running, but it doesn't seem to be grabbing anything and updating the variables.

I'm also thinking that I have a glaring omission in the code that does not account for users going back and changing an entry. I think that will throw the Answered variable off. However I have no idea how to account for that.

I'm trying to keep the code as basic as possible as I have upwards of 20 different ratings to find across 12 different foms, where the number of drop downs relating to each rating can vary. So the more compact I can make it the better.

Comment: Side note: please review this guidance https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions on *not including* text like "thankyou", "new here" into the post.

Comment: Sorry about that, thank you for cleaning it up for me. I will remember that for future posts.